# Как правильно форматировать код?

Tags: поддержка, подсветка-синтаксиса, блок-кода

Как правильней всего оформлять код при вставке? Можно ли где-то выбрать подсветку синтаксиса конкретного языка и т.д? Прошу простить, если вопрос слишком банальный

Comment: Посмотрите на панели инструментов есть `{}`, что служит для форматирования кода или `ctrl + k`